Minification lazy image php
The issue with lazy images not being displayed after minification is likely due to the removal of essential whitespaces within the data-src attribute in your img tags.
When the HTML is minified, the whitespaces around attribute values can sometimes be crucial for the correct functionality of JavaScript libraries that rely on specific formatting.
how to avoid this issue
i've skipped this script to get my lazy image displayed
<!-- debut -->
<script>
function result_filtre(art) {
    document.getElementById("resultat_filtre" + art).innerHTML = \'<br />&nbsp;<center><img src="https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/theme/images/loader.gif"  alt="loader"  class="loading3" /></center><br />\';
    $.ajax({
            url: "include/resulta_filtre_dest_og_new.php?libelle_art=" + art,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                var ch = html.split("###");
                document.getElementById("resultat_filtre" + art).innerHTML = ch[0];
            }
        });
        return false;
}

function result_img(art) {
    document.getElementById("resultat_img" + art).innerHTML = \'<br />&nbsp;<center><img src="https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/theme/images/loader.gif"  alt="loader"  class="loading3" /></center><br />\';

    $("#resultat_img" + art).load("include/liste_img2_og.php?libelle_art=" + art, function(response, status, xhr) {
        // error handling
        if (status == "error") {
            $("#resultat_img" + art).html("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function sub_devis(id, art) {
    document.getElementById("id_tarif" + art).value = id;
    document.getElementById("page_dev" + id).submit();
}
</script>
<!-- fin -->


This is not a question and it has nothing to do with php.

ok let me explain i need to minify my code source which include lazy image when i minify it i didn't get the image displayed, have you faced with this pb in php
